# Android : get information(title, artist, album..) from Notification player

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-music-player

Notification player displays information about the song I played through the app

I want to know How get information from Notification player
(artist, title, album img src...)

But I don't know the code to access the existing notification bar.

Can you tell me the information related to this?

I'll say thank you in advance.

Comment: NotificationListenerService
Can I use this?

Comment: Yes you can use it, I suggest you to read [QuickLyric](https://github.com/QuickLyric/QuickLyric)'s source code.